# EXIF-Metadata not managed correctly in iCloud Photos => Wrong Date & GPS Groupings

Tags: icloud, photos, gps, metadata, exif

I have uploaded ca. 2500 pictures from my PC to the iCloud using icloud.com interface.

However, iCloud doesn't seem to be using the EXIF-Metadata in the picture files.

I have confirmed the EXIF-Metadata is actually in the files.

For example, I have a photo file with EXIF-Metadata stating

```
ModifyDate                2017:12:24 15:10:46     
DateTimeOriginal          2017:12:24 15:10:46 
CreateDate                2017:12:24 15:10:46
```

I.e. the photo was taken on December 24th, 2017.

However, when I upload it to iCloud using iCloud.com, it groups the photo under whatever date I uploaded the picture to iCloud (e.g. today, May 8, 2018)

The GPS-Data, and probably other data stored in the EXIF-Metadata is also not managed correctly in iCloud.

For Example, a picture I uploaded from my PC, which is located in Europe, is grouped under a European location on iCloud.com. However, the EXIF metadate indicates (correctly), that this picture was taken in North America.

Anyone have a solution to this? As far as I can tell, many people have this issue, but I have not seen any fix by apple or any workaround/solution.

Comment: I cannot seem to be able to reproduce this issue with photos that were clicked with a DSLR(exported from PS) and that were clicked with iPhone and exported/shared to Mac. If you are able to see the metadata in finder, then it would show up in iCloud under right date. Not sure about location.

Comment: What does exit show for actual location? Just because there is date metadata doesn’t mean the location is preserved or there in the first place.